# Remove white element on the top

Tags: html, css

I've come to a problem where I added a navigation bar that is supposed to be at the top of the page, but when you first open the page, it's at the bottom, and the viewport shows a text and a background image. Then, as your scroll down, the navigation bar moves to the top and stays at the top. But, as I put the background image, seems like the background image won't be at the very top of the page like on this screenshot when I first load the page: https://imgur.com/a/vPlCoKv..

My best guess is that it's occupied by the navigation bar which is supposed to be at the top(?) Correct me if I'm wrong though.

Is there a way to make the background image apppear at the very top of the image?
or maybe I did something wrong?

```css
/* General Styles */
html,
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.fullpage {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.fullpage::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1707343848610-16f9afe1ae23');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center calc(0% - 60px);
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: -1;
}

.top-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 0 20px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.logo-and-name {
  font-family: 'Marhey', sans-serif;
  font-optical-sizing: auto;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  position: absolute;
  left: 90px;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.brand-name {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.logo-and-name .brand-name:first-child {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.logo-and-name .brand-name:last-child {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.nav-links {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav-links li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 15px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-links li {
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.nav-links li a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.fixed-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>AMADEUS GAVRIEL TATAMING</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kode+Mono:wght@400..700&family=Marhey:wght@300..700&family=Roboto+Mono:ital,wght@0,100..700;1,100..700&family=Slackside+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="top-nav">
        <div class="logo-and-name">
            <a href="#home" class="brand-name">Amadeus</a>
            <a href="#home" class="brand-name">Gavriel's</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <section class="fullpage" id="journey">Journey of Mine</section>
            
        <p>Copyright © Amadeus Gavriel Tataming. 2024</p>
    </main>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a517578ea4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="tooltips.js"></script>
    <script src="frontpage.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="frontpagebg.js"></script> -->
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm really confused as this is my first project. It'd help a lot. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't get what you are trying to do? the expected result?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. The problem I'm trying to move the picture up from the position. Like in this picture : imgur.com/a/vPlCoKv, my background picture seems to be placed a little below from the top of the page. I already tried adding padding and margin and the picure seem to won't move. Is there anything to

Answer (score 0):

Change `bottom: 0;` to `top: 0` in `.top-nav`.

`bottom: 0;` (with `position: absolute`) means that it's positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor (i.e. an ancestor element that has a `position` setting) or to the initial containing block.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. The problem I'm trying to move the picture up from the position. Like in this picture : https://imgur.com/a/vPlCoKv, my background picture seems to be placed a little below from the top of the page. I already tried adding padding and margin and the picure seem to won't move. Is there anything to work around it?